# How to replace icons with Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on some interactive player icons for a Spotify Clone application.
I have no problem getting the icon/button to play the song file, but I can't seem to figure out how to replace the icon classes (from 'fa-solid-play' to 'fa-solid-pause' for ex.) using an OnClick event.

At first I tried to change the classes using the innerHTML.text method but I found that just nested a new icon inside the already existing one.
The following code returns classList = null when I call the function, and the same is true for any kind of removeClass/ addClass alternative.
I feel I may have to refactor some of the HTML for this to make sense perhaps.

For reference this a snippet of the HTML:

```
 <div class="Player-Icons">
   <div class="Icon-Div">
     <div class="Shuffle-Icon" onclick="shuffle()"><i class="fa-solid fa-shuffle"></i></div>
     <div class="Previous-Icon" onclick="previous()"><i class="fa-solid fa-backward"></i></div>
     <div class="Play-Icon" onclick="playsong()" ><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-play"  aria-hidden='true' id="Triangle-Play"></i></div>
     <div class="Next-Icon" onclick="next()"><i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-forward-step"></i></div>
     <div class="Repeat-Icon" onclick="shuffle()"><i class="fa-solid fa-repeat"></i></div>
   </div>
```

JS Snippet:

```
    { let play = document.querySelector('.Play-Icon ');
let next = document.querySelector('.Next-Icon');
let current_title = document.querySelector('.Song-Title');
let current_artist = document.querySelector('.Song-Artist');
let current_image = document.querySelector('.Current-Image');
let slider = document.querySelector('.Slider');
let time = document.querySelector('.Song-Start');
let remaining_time = document.querySelector('.Song-Finish');
let volume = document.querySelector('.Volume-Slider');

let timer;
let autoplay = 0;

let index_no = 0;
let playing_song = false;

//const playIconClassName = 'fa-circle-play'
//const pauseIconClassName = 'fa-circle-pause'

//Audio Element
let track = document.createElement('audio');

//Song List 
let All_song = [
{
  name: "No Ceilings",
  path: "Playlist /Track/No Ceilings.mp3",
  img: "Image/image1.jpg",
  artist: "Tony Shhnow",
}
]

//All Functions

//Load the track
function load_track(index_no){
track.src = All_song[index_no].path;
current_title.innerHTML =  'No Ceilings'; //All_song[index_no].name
current_artist.innerHTML = 'Tony Shhnow';
current_image = All_song[index_no].img;
track.load();
console.log('Current artist is ' + current_artist.innerHTML);
console.log('Current title is ' + current_title.innerHTML );
}

load_track(index_no);

//Checker for current song / If else 
function justplay(){
 if(playing_song==false) {
    playsong();
} /*else{
    pausesong();
}*/
```

}

```
//Function for playing sample song
function playsong(){
 track.play();
 playing_song = true

if(playing_song==true)  {
    document.querySelector('Play-Icon').classList.remove('fa-circle-play');
    document.querySelector('Play-Icon').classList.add('fa-circle-pause');
    console.log('btnpressed');
}
```

}

At first I tried to change the classes using the innerHTML.text method but I found that just nested a new icon inside the already existing one.
The following code returns classList = null when I call the function, and the same is true for any kind of removeClass/ addClass alternative.
I feel I may have to refactor some of the HTML for this to make sense perhaps.

Comment: maybe the problem is the selector? `.querySelector('.Play-Icon')` you are missing the dot

Comment: Yes the problem was the selector and referencing the parent div instead of the icon itself. I don't know why it took me so long to figure it out lol. Thankyou either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Missing a "."

`querySelector('div')` will find a `div` element.
What you are referring to is a class name, so you need a `.`.

Try changing

```
if(playing_song==true)  {
    document.querySelector('Play-Icon').classList.remove('fa-circle-play');
    document.querySelector('Play-Icon').classList.add('fa-circle-pause');
    console.log('btnpressed');
}
```

to

```
if(playing_song==true)  {
    document.querySelector('.Play-Icon').classList.remove('fa-circle-play');
    document.querySelector('.Play-Icon').classList.add('fa-circle-pause');
    console.log('btnpressed');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. The solution was missing a dot as you mentioned, but I was referencing the parent div instead of the icon class and that seems to have fixed it.